# "The service 'serializer' has a dependency on a non-existent service 'entity.manager'"

Tags: upgrading, 9

I have a multidomain site and recently I update from D8 to D9.

In my multidomain site I have 2 websites, sharing core and modules, but with different DB.

One of them after update works correctly but the other one not.

I got this error:

> The service "serializer" has a dependency on a non-existent service "entity.manager"

[image: error]

In this last 2 days I search and tried some fixes but no luck.

What I tried:

- uninstall contrib modules
- disable views
- uninstall/delete paragraphs
- tried a couple of patches

If I return to D8 everything works good.

My modules list:

[image: modules list]

Dind't find anything related with theses modules and current error.

Any thouths about this migration error?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Seems one of your custom or contrib modules isn't D9 ready yet. Scan the modules folder for `entity.manager`.

Comment: That service name is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

After @leymannx and @Kevin tips I could fix my problem, I will leave step by step what I have done, hope help anyone else :)

1. Set my sites do Drupal 8 again
2. Search inside my modules folder if any module use "entity.manager"
3. Update those modules according module page
4. Update D8 to D9 with composer
5. Run update.php (this give couple more errors about compatibility in some modules)
6. Update those modules

I have a couple of custom modules and custom theme, in those I replace

> core: ^8.8

with

> core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9

Also have couple more contrib modules with the same problem, so I created a patch for those modules.

After all that could run update.php and everything works as expected.